# How to make a regex to check for other symbols than a given string?

Tags: c#, regex

I need to make a regex that checks if an input string contains symbols other than symbols that I have in the charRange string.

given string:

```
string charRange = 
  "ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZabcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz0123456789.,:;-?! '()$%&\"";
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For a given range and value

```
string charRange =
  "ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZabcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz0123456789.,:;-?! '()$%&\"";

string value = "-7Rt1Vp2RV";
```

Linq solution (shorter and more readable):

```
bool hasOutOfRangeChar = value.Any(c => !charRange.Contains(c));
```

If you insist on regular expressions:

```
bool hasOutOfRangeChar = !Regex.IsMatch(value, "^[" + Regex.Escape(charRange) + "]*$");
```

please, notice `Regex.Escape` since `-` has a *special meaning* when within `[...]` - *range* form to; e.g. `;-?` means any symbol from `;` to `?`

Answer (score 2):

Here is full example how you should use this :

```
    string charRange = @"ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZabcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz0123456789.,:;\-?! '()$%&""";
    foreach(Match a in new Regex("[^"+charRange+"]").Matches("-7Rt1Vp2RV"))
    {
        Console.WriteLine(a.Value);
    }
```

`-` is special symbol and must be with `\`.
That was the reason you get true.

Comment: This is not correct because some chars are still special inside character classes.

Comment: I don't get why I get True when running this
`Console.WriteLine(new Regex("[^"+charRange+"]").IsMatch("-7Rt1Vp2RV"));`

Comment: @AlexGeorgievskiy because `^` is meaning to search for any character that is not specified in group

Answer (score 1):

If you're just checking whether a string doesn't contain a character in another string, use Linq:

```
var stringContainsOtherSymbol = !stringToCheck.All(c => stringOfAllowedChars.Contains(c))
```

Using Regex is just going to trip you up because you have to escape regex metacharacters in `stringOfAllowedChars`.